# Updating Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderDocx and Sitecore.WordOCX on Sitecore 10.1

Tags: upgrade

I'm currently upgrading my code from the `Sitecore 8.2` project to `Sitecore 10.1`, and I noticed the `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderDocx` and `Sitecore.WordOCX` are not in `Sitecore.kernel` for the version `10.1`.

Is there any substitute for these namespaces on `Sitecore 10.1`?
Also, does anyone know where to find documentation for all functions available in the `Sitecore 10.1` dlls?

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Check dll Telerik.Web.UI.dll, I can see DocxRenderer class here, see if this helps you.

Comment: I didn't find the DocxRenderer class on my Telerik.web.ui.dll. I'm using telerik version 2020.3.1021.45

Comment: I can see this in your dll version as well, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see `DocxRenderer` class under namespace `Telerik.Web.UI.ExportInfrastructure` in `Telerik.Web.UI.dll`, check this, this can help you.

[image]